# how to click a "ng" object using selenium with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to automate clicking on some web elements in order to monitor the web page.

apparently this page is written using AngularJS. I came to this conclusion due to the ng-model, ng-repeat and so on used in this page.
using this code I try to click a specific element but I get an error that the item is not clickable

```py
driver.get("https://sales.aig.co.il/travel")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'chkDestination-title156')))
elm156 = driver.find_element_by_id("chkDestination-title156")
elm156.click()
```

no matter what I try to click, Im getting the same error: is not clickable...
this is the complete error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55004/devtools/browser/a430d472-d53a-4ead-a199-a60d75a2fba6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AIGtravel.py", line 16, in <module>
    elm156.click()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <label class="ng-binding countries-item_name" for="chkDestination156" id="chkDestination-title156">...</label> is not clickable at point (923, 536). Other element would receive the click: <input type="checkbox" name="selectedDestination" id="chkDestination156" ng-model="step1VM.sharedPolicyService.destinationsSelectionObject.items[$index].selected" data-ng-change="step1VM.selectionChanged()" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" aria-invalid="false">
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

Comment: What does the rest of the error say?  Does it indicate that another element gets the click?

Comment: Please directly edit your question and update the entire stacktrace error.  Reading code in comments isn't feasible.  The stacktrace is pointing you to the element that is preventing access to your targeted element.  I'm not sure what `<input type="checkbox" name="selectedDestination" id="chkDestination156">` is doing.  In these cases, there's often a loading "spinner" icon that blocks the page until fully loaded.  You'll just have to dig into the page source.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been digging into this a lot and finally came to a solution using `WebDriverWait` and this code:

```
driver.get("https://sales.aig.co.il/travel")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'chkDestination- 
title156')))
elm156 = driver.find_element_by_id("chkDestination156")
elm156.click()
```